# Print data.frame with column names with spaces

Tags: r

My dataframe looks like this:

```
sum <- data.frame(
    "default LS" = rnorm(3),
    "fit LS" = rnorm(3), 
    "gradient dMNLL/dLS" = rnorm(3)
)
```

Now, the spaces got converted to `.` (dots), for syntax reasons:

```
  default.LS      fit.LS gradient.dMNLL.dLS
1  0.1157615  0.06711939          1.5897061
2  1.1819154  1.11368192         -0.1730422
3  0.1531863 -0.63845188          0.6946397
```

I don't mind in the code, but for presentation purposes, I would like to print it with spaces.

Is there a way to print the data.frame with spaces?

Is there a way to print data.frame with custom column names?

Comment: You can use `check.names = FALSE` when creating the data.frame. That only makes working with this data.frame a nuisance because you need syntax like `sum$"fit LS"`. Better to do `names(sum) <- gsub(".", " ", names(sum), fixed = TRUE)` before printing.

Comment: thanks @Roland, I didn't know about this option! Feel free to post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution mentioned by @Roland also for others as an answer:

Use `check.names = FALSE` when creating the `data.frame`:

```
sum <- data.frame(
    "default LS" = rnorm(3),
    "fit LS" = rnorm(3), 
    "gradient dMNLL/dLS" = rnorm(3),
    check.names = FALSE
)
```

But that makes working with this data.frame a nuisance because you need syntax like `sum$"fit LS"`. Better to do:

```
names(sum) <- gsub(".", " ", names(sum), fixed = TRUE)
```

right before printing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use tibble objects from the `tidyverse` packages.

```
 library(tibble)
 data <- tibble("Variable with space"=letters)
 data
```

Even though it has ticks around the variable name when printed directly, it doesn't stick around for other printing situations (like plots or tables).

Comment: Ironically, given that almost all tidyverse packages assume column names do not contain spaces, by default they don't remove them

Answer (score 0):

```r
sum <- data.frame(
  "default LS" = rnorm(3),
  "fit LS" = rnorm(3), 
  "gradient dMNLL/dLS" = rnorm(3)
)
names(sum)<- gsub("\\."," ", make.names(names(sum), unique = T))
sum
#>   default LS     fit LS gradient dMNLL dLS
#> 1 -0.7607631 -0.6488190         -2.1846567
#> 2  1.3633617 -0.1891804          1.0127126
#> 3  0.1476440  0.6775571         -0.7808632
sum[["default LS"]]
#> [1] -0.7607631  1.3633617  0.1476440
```

To select a particular column, the column name passed in `""` or ``